# Finding integer solution.(Problem from UGC NET 2015)

Tags: number-theory, permutations

What is the total number of positive integer solutions to the equation $(x_{1}+x_2+x_3)$$(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4)$ = 15 ?
Will I have to decompose the equation into equation of $x$ and equation of $y$ then solve ?
Then I also have a problem in decomposing the right hand side.
How to solve such type of problems?
Any insight?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to add something to Paolo's answer, you'll be better off if you know 'Stars And Bars' theorem for solving general versions of the above problem. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: That's helpful.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sum x_i \ge 3$ and $\sum y_i \ge 4$. Considering the factorizations of $15$, we have
$$
15=\underbrace{(x_1+x_2+x_3)}_{=3}\underbrace{(y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4)}_{=5}.
$$
Hence all the variables are $1$, except one $y_i$. This can be done in $4$ ways.

Comment: Thanks,nice explanation.

Comment: $$=1;=15$$  $$=-1;=-15$$  $$=3;=5$$ $$=-3;=-5$$ $$=5;=3$$ $$=-5;=-3$$  
 $$=15;=1$$ $$=-15;=-1$$

Comment: Sorry ,what is this? ,I can't get it ..

Comment: @individ the variables $x_i$ are $y_i$ are positive..